# ASP.NET user browse selected/restricted raw data from sql-server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, custom-view

In an ASP.NET WebForms application I would like to allow the end-user to browse selected raw data in an sql-server database.

However, I would like to restrict access for the user to only view some of the data based on the username.

I'm not sure how to do this in a way that is possible for the user to understand, since SQL is not necessarily known to the user.

What options do I have here?

---

As a basis for this I have considered creating one sql function per table in question. That function should return the data that the user is allowed to view, e.g.,

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_RawData_Employee(@username nvarchar(256))
RETURNS TABLE
AS ( SELECT * FROM Employee 
  WHERE [@username is allowed to view the given Employee] )
```

In a webpage the end-user might then type an SQL-like statement like

```
SELECT Name, HireDate FROM ((Employee))
```

where `(([TableName]))` then could be replaced by `ufn_RawData_[TableName]([UserName])` before calling the database.
(For security reasons such calls could then be performed by a sql user whose *only* permissions are SELECT permissions to these functions.)

However, this approach might be too difficult for the end-user. I would like to know if an easier/user-friendlier solution exists for the end-user to browse selected raw data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only showing the user data from one table, or one view (which would probably be more useful) then yes you could store the name of that view in a table and retrieve it with a function.  You could then display the data in pages, and make sure your standard select scripts have a built in search function if necessary.

There is no need for the user to write SQL if they are only getting data from one table or view.  If you need to provide multiple potential tables/  views, then let them choose from a drop down, but it doesn't sound worthwhile to allow them to write their own SQL queries.